# Color Bar on a 2D Time Series

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, time-series

I found a way to plot my netCDF variables where x is time, y is chlorophyll concentrations and z is latitude. The way I did it is different how a lot of others did it so it's hard trying to find what I'm actually meant to do so that I can a color bar for latitude. Below is my code. It's essentially a 2D time series plot. My chlorophyll variable default is a 3D with dimensions of time, latitude and longitude but I am able to change it's dimensions/shape.

Below is the code I used and [here's an image of my plot, all the colors are latitude, and that's what I want a color bar for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WISQY.png)

```
chl = nc.Dataset(r'/data/GEO301/Final_Projects/ChristianAmandaRachael/chl.nc')
tc = np.array(chl.variables['time'])
lat_c = chl.variables['latitude']
lon_c = chl.variables['longitude']
chla = (chl.variables['chla'])

# Converts Unix Time to Datetime
def myfromtimestampfunction(timestamp):
    return dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
def myvectorizer(input_func):
    def output_func(array_of_numbers):
        return [input_func(a) for a in array_of_numbers]
    return output_func
date_convert =  myvectorizer(myfromtimestampfunction)
time = date_convert(tc)

# Changes dimensions of variables
tc, ygrid = np.meshgrid(lat_c, time) # time; y_grid in the dimensions of latitude and time
z_lat = chla[:,:,0] # chl variable in dimensions of time and latitude

# Plot Chlorophyll
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (22,10))
cc = plt.plot(ygrid, z_lat, '.', markersize = 5)
    
plt.xlabel('Time', fontsize = 15, labelpad = 12)
plt.xlim(15940,17780)

plt.ylabel('Chl-a Concentration (mg/m$^{3}$)', fontsize = 15, labelpad = 12)
plt.ylim(0,1.3)
plt.title('Daily Chlorophyll Concentration (2013-08-30 to 2022-08-30): Californian Current', fontsize = 17)

plt.show()
```